# Clear data in form. Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, controls

I would like to clear data in this form.
Would you tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
            RadioButton2.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
     ctrl.Checked = False
End If
```

In your current code you are looping through all the controls but only updating the Checked property of RadioButton2.

Comment: That not working. this code that seems normal is not working too.        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
                CType(ctrl, RadioButton).Checked = False
            End If

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me :

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
    'reset the checked property to ALL your radioButtons     
    DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButton).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```

You'll loop in all controls in your form.